# Решение уравнений в android studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent

В целом теоретический вопрос. Имеется: Приложение передающее данные с plain text в новую активность(intent)
Нужно реализовать:решение квадратного уравнения.
У меня уже есть класс решающий их:

```
System.out.println("Программа решает квадратное уравнение вида:");
System.out.println("ax^2 + bx + c = 0");
System.out.println("Введите a, b и c:");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

a = in.nextDouble();
b = in.nextDouble();
c = in.nextDouble();

D = b * b - 4 * a * c;
if (D > 0) {
    double x1, x2;
    x1 = (-b - Math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
    x2 = (-b + Math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
    System.out.println("Корни уравнения: x1 = " + x1 + ", x2 = " + x2);
}
else if (D == 0) {
    double x;
    x = -b / (2 * a);
    System.out.println("Уравнение имеет единственный корень: x = " + x);
}
else {
    System.out.println("Уравнение не имеет действительных корней!");
}
```

Но как этот код реализовать в android studio мне не совсем понятно. 
Возможно, что мой код в корне неправилен и поэтому его нельзя реализовать в андроид-приложении, но я не знаю как сделать по другому.

Comment: С консолью пользователь не может взаимодействовать на телефоне, а в остальном ваш код рабочий. Так что все что вам надо придумать, это новый UI.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, дело в том, что я не знаю из одного plaintext вычленить a,b,c,x

Comment: Так а текст этот откуда берется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй три Plain Text для ввода значений a, b и c, так будет удобнее.
Бери из них значения:

```
EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_plainText);
String aStr = a.getText().toString();
```

И так с каждой переменной.
Создай в своём классе метод, в который будешь передавать значения переменной.
Все **System.out.println** придется убрать.
Из этого метода возвращай решение, а его можешь передать в другое activity и там как-нибудь его отобразить.

Comment: Да у меня были подобные идеи, спасибо. Буду пытаться реализовывать;)